# Share Visual Studio projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm running Visual Studio C++ and C# Express 2010 on two computers. I'd like to have a shared Projects directory. What are my options?

Comment: Use source control.

Answer (score 1):

You have many options.

- You could share your projects directory out from one computer and use it on the other.
- You could store your projects on a NAS or server share
- You could store the projects 'in the cloud' using something like CVS, SVN, etc
- You could store your projects in a shared online storage system, like DropBox.

The options are endless.

It all boils down to what you actually want to achieve.